# Python Web Scraping Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web, beautifulsoup

Buenas dias tardes o noches, estoy intentando obtener desde la pagina de transfermarket.mx los jugadores mas valiosos de la Liga Mexicana de Futbol con su nombre y respectivo valor pero al momento de devolverme los nombres de los jugadores me duplica el primer nombre viendose algo asi

Players          Values

0   Florian Thauvin  14.00 mill. €

1   Florian Thauvin  10.00 mill. €

2  Carlos Rodríguez  10.00 mill. €

3   Luis Romo   9.00 mill. €

4    Orbelín Pineda   8.00 mill. €

Que me puede estar fallando? Anexo codigo

```
import requests from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
 Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

 page ='https://www.transfermarkt.mx/liga-mx-clausura/marktwerte/wettbewerb/MEX1'
 pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
 pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

 #Jugadores
 Players = pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})

 #Valor
 Values = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})

 PlayersList = []
 ValuesList = []

 for i in range(0,25):
  PlayersList.append(Players[i].text)
  ValuesList.append(Values[i].text)

  df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":PlayersList,"Values":ValuesList})

 respuesta=df.head()

print(respuesta)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un problema es que la página web presenta dos tablas, una titulada "Valores más altos" y otra titulada "Últimos cambios":

[image: Ejemplo]

En ambas tablas pueden aparecer jugadores repetidos, y el método con que lo extraes te mezcla resultados de ambas tablas.

Otro problema es que en la cabecera, arriba del todo de la página sale también el "jugador más valioso":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y de ahí estás pillando también al jugador "Florian Thauvin". En total tu lista `Players` tiene 31 elementos, en lugar de los 25 que debería tener (uno por el más valioso, otros 25 por la tabla "Valores más altos" y otros 5 por la tabla "Últimos cambios")

Puedes restringir la búsqueda a la primera tabla. Por desgracia no tiene un "id" para identificarla de forma única, pero podemos basarnos en que es más ancha, lo que han logrado dándole la clase "large-8", así que podemos buscar el primer `<div>` con esa clase, para después, dentro de él, realizar ya la búsqueda que hacías tú.

Es decir:

```py
# ... omito la request
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

table = pageSoup.find("div", {"class": "large-8"})

#Jugadores
Players = table.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})

#Valor
Values = table.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})

# el resto es igual como tenías...
```

Resultado:

```html
              Players          Values
0     Florian Thauvin  14.00 mill. € 
1    Carlos Rodríguez  10.00 mill. € 
2           Luis Romo  10.00 mill. € 
3      Orbelín Pineda   9.00 mill. € 
4  Jonathan Rodríguez   8.00 mill. €
```

Comment: Excelente amigo, me funciono perfecto, muchas gracias!!